# Adding multiple background images/colors to a navigation bar

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

Just wondering if anyone can help me out here. What i'm looking to do (ugly as it is) is add two background colors to a nav bar on a site. Basically all of the list items will have a red background except one which needs to have a  blue background. I tried to solve this using 1 long background image but this didn't work cross browser as the positioning of text changed between Chrome and Firefox.

What im wondering is if there is a way that I can give all the elements a red background but maybe use a span or something to select the single element in the navigation that I want to have a blue background?

This is what im looking to achieve (like I said incredibly ugly I know)

[image: dual colored navigation]

Any ideas or help anyone can give me would really be great

Thanks!

Comment: Post your `HTML` and `CSS` as a Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Is the coloured element static, or is it an indication of the selected element? (The part of the menu the user is currently at)

Comment: Hi the colored element is static, the idea would then be to have a common rollover effect for all list items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give the whole navigation bar a background, but all of the elements of your navigation bar. Then you can give one a class called `blue` and in CSS: `.blue { background: blue; }` or something like that.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/A7RMA/2/

Comment: This should be marked up as an `un-ordered` list `<ul>` rather than span tags.

Comment: yeah you're right, I usually use ul's for this too, but for this example spans were just a bit easier and quicker to use. But I updated the fiddle.

Comment: Hi thanks for that i think this may work, im going to go and try it width background images and i'll let you know if it worked out!

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oMeZUBu/1/edit)**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Samples</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```
nav ul{
  list-style:none;
}
nav a{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  padding:10px 20px;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
nav a.active, nav a:hover{
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for your static blue item, use the CSS advised by DRP96:

```
.bluemenu
{ 
    background: blue; 
}
```

for the other items, do the same, but red:

```
.redmenu
{ 
    background: red; 
}
```

to make the red menu's blue when hovering over them you can use:

```
A:hover
{ 
    background: green; 
}
```

(replace 'A' in the above fragment with whatever object you use for the menu items. This should also be the same as the items to which you apply the redmenu and bluemenu classes)